# sw & update window says Intel Corporations: Unknown

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have ubuntu 18.04 installed on my system.
I am getting the error:

```
 $ nvidia-smi
```

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
> driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
> running.

I am following the link:
[install latest proprietary driver](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/)

```
$ hwinfo --gfxcard --short
```

> graphics card:
> Intel VGA compatible controller
>
> Primary display adapter: #20

```
@lc2530hz:~$ sudo lshw -C display
```

> *-display
> description: VGA compatible controller
> product: Intel Corporation
> vendor: Intel Corporation
> physical id: 2
> bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
> version: 00
> width: 64 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
> configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
> resources: irq:144 memory:8d000000-8dffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

Then it asks for pressing the windows key. The remaining steps are:

pressing Super Key-→update manager-→Settings-→Additional Drivers, I am getting following screen:

[image: sw & updates window image]

Somebody please guide me what should I do now?

Zulfi.

==
The system information:

$ sudo dmidecode -t 1
[sudo] password for zulfi:

> ## dmidecode 3.1 Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs. SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.
>
> Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes System Information    Manufacturer:
> Notebook                          Product Name: N8xxEZ
> Version: Not Applicable                     Serial Number: Not
> Applicable                    UUID:
> 58315B0C-1064-4E3D-A328-E93B5ACFB7F6  Wake-up Type: Power Switch  SKU
> Number: Not Applicable                    Family: Not Applicable

Comment: NVIDIA drivers don't work with an Intel card.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1305679/edit) your question and add details about your system hardware, i.e. Motherboard type, manufacturer, etc.  But so far all that you have shown is an Intel video card and `nvidia-smi` will not work with Intel.

Comment: Isn't that an Intel wifi card? The driver is `iwlwifi`

Comment: @Terrance, I have provided the system information above.

Comment: Unfortunately, that information still doesn't help.  Who makes your laptop?  What is the model of it?  Beyond that there is still nothing indicating that you have an NVIDIA video card in your system.